# JS code returning error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm new to JS and i had to use it for Cloud Code Parse feature. I have a class called "user_picture", through the code i query all the objects and go through it's "City" attribute. i want the response to be an array of unique city names. Anyway, here is the code i'm working on:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("cities", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query("user_picture");
query.find({
success: function(results) {
    var cities = new Array();

    for (var object in results){
        var tempArray = [object.get("city")];

        if (cities.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
                if (cities[i].get("city") == object.get("city")) {
                    break;
                } else if (i == cities.length-1) {
                    cities = cities.concat(tempArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    response.success (cities);
}, error: function() {
    response.error("Error");
}
});});
```

However, when i run this function i receive the following error:

```
Error: TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'get'
at query.find.success (main.js:15:30)
at Parse.js:2:5786
at r (Parse.js:2:4981)
at Parse.js:2:4531
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.E.each.E.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:666)
at n.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:4482)
at r (Parse.js:2:5117)
at Parse.js:2:4531
at Array.forEach (native) (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)
```

And the response returns null. I tried printing one object from the results array in order to make sure i'm receiving the right query, and it's printing fine the city. What could be the problem?

Comment: What kind of object is `results`? It's telling you it has no method `get`. Maybe you mean `object.city`?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: @ppoliani i couldn't identify the error as the code is running on Parse.com servers.

Comment: @Mathletics results is of type Array. Each object in it is of type dictionary (iOS speaking). i tried to return results[0].get("city") it returns fine the city for the specified object

Answer (score 1):

The `for in` loop iterates through all the keys of an object literal. Since `results` is an Array it will iterate through the keys of the Array, which are '0', '1' etc.

This means that the `object` variable will hold those key vales. And since they are not objects they don't have a method called get.

You need a `forEach` loop instead.

```
results.forEach(function(object){
    var tempArray = [object.get("city")];

    if (cities.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
            if (cities[i].get("city") == object.get("city")) {
                break;
            } else if (i == cities.length-1) {
                cities = cities.concat(tempArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

Or if you're targeting ES3 then you should use a for loop

```
for(var i = 0, length = results.length; i< length; i++){
    var object = results[i];

    var tempArray = [object.get("city")];

    if (cities.length > 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
            if (cities[i].get("city") == object.get("city")) {
                break;
            } else if (i == cities.length-1) {
                cities = cities.concat(tempArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recall working with Parse objects a bit and there seemed to be times to access them as an object (by direct parameter access) and sometimes by using the `get` method and it looks like you're mixing up the array access and object (from Parse) access methods.

Also, your list generator doesn't seem like it's really building a unique list.  You only check to see if the current city is the same as the city you're going to add.

I might do something more like this (for the success method):

```
function(parseResults) {
  var cities = {};
  var ii=0;
  var nResults = parseResults.length
  for(;ii<nResults;++ii) {
    cities[result.get('city')] = 1
  }
  var citiesArray = cities.keys();
  response.success(citiesArray);
}
```

What we do here is build up an object whose keys are city names.  Then return the keys as an array.  What this does for us is automatically build a unique list because object keys should be unique.

If the `result.get` gives you problems, try replacing it with `result.city`.  But i suspect the error you were seeing with your first example was trying to call `get` on the Array element.

Comment: Why do you provide an example that uses a specific library? There is not need to include underscore.js in your project just to iterate through an array.

Comment: Point taken.  I've updated the code snippet to use vanilla JS.  This code only assumes a modern javascript (ECMAScript 5) which includes the `keys()` method.